# Inner product in application

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have a little doubt. The theoric definition of the dot product always assumes both vectors are in the same space (as is an inner product), usually in applications there are situations in which, even though both vectors are in $\mathbb{R}^n$, they, apparently, do not belong to the same space. For example, when I have a vector of prices per share and a vector of shares held, they are can't be propperly added, but their inner product is an useful quantity.

Though in the use of the operation there is no limitation, as there is no need to define a different inner product (opposite for example in the case of general relativity and the term $c^2$ when defining the inner product), I am not sure that this "separation" has any theoretical relevance.

Comment: Without vector addition and scalar multiplication it doesn't make much sense to model them as vectors. The inner product relies on that additional structure for bilinearity but without them being vectors that doesn't mean much either.

Comment: You can make an inner product with weights to make the addition make sense. For example, consider the energy of the harmonic oscillator as a quadratic form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ with coordiantes $(x,v)$: $\frac{m}{2}v^2 + \frac{1}{2}kx^2$